# When will the site get Community Promotion Ads?

Tags: support, promotion

This site has graduated over a month ago now and I'm wondering when we are to expect the post for *Community Promotion Ads*. Please don't misunderstand this question as complaint or making any pressure on the SE team. I just like to know if there is anything formal that stands in the way of getting those, like do we have to explicitly request them somehow, or will they naturally emerge after just a bit more waiting time? In the former case, what needs to be done to apply for them? In the latter case, is there any rough approximation of the timeframe when they will emerge?

Comment: I went up a hierarchy level: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251219/162011.